# Cooling photons to a solid state

Tags: photons, temperature, speed-of-light, electrical-resistance, optical-materials

Can we cool photons so the stop moving completely?

So they can behave like particles in a solid.

Answer (score 2):

No. In free space, all photons- regardless of their frequency, and therefore their energy- travel always and forever at c, the speed of light.